# Text displays multiple times but when I try this, it doesnt display at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, jsx

The text kept displaying multiple times but when I thought about a way of making it only display one it didnt display at all. I got a variable and set it to 0, There is a timer that sets it to 0 every 2 seconds. The function can only work when the value is 0 but as the function runs it adds sets the value to 1 so it cant run again until the timer sets it to 0

`

```
var messagees1 = 0;

function resetVariable() {
        messagees1 = 0;
    }
    setInterval(resetVariable, 2000);

socket.on('messageReceived', (data) => {
        if (data.senderr === userName && messagees1 == 0) {
            setChatMessages((prevMessages) => [
                ...prevMessages,
                { senderName: 'you', message: data.messagee },
            ]);
        } else if (data.sendpartner === userName && messagees1 == 0 ) {
            setChatMessages((prevMessages) => [
                ...prevMessages,
                { senderName: partner, message: data.messagee.trim() },
            ]);
        }
        messagees1 = 1

    });
```

`

I tried rearranging the positing of the if statements when the messagges is equal to zero but it didnt work. When i removed it, it displayed the text but multiple times. The main problem is the function is being called multiple times but I dont know how to fix that and I think this way that I am doing is easier

Comment: Don't, you can prevent it by using [debounce or throttle.](https://iq.js.org/questions/react/how-to-prevent-a-function-from-being-called-multiple-times)

Comment: I am really new to javascript, how can i do that?

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation I tried using debounce but it only adds time before the text appears in which multiple appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, i got it to work

```
socket.on('messageReceived', (data) => {
        if (data.senderr === userName && messagees1 == 0) {
            setChatMessages((prevMessages) => [
                ...prevMessages,
                { senderName: 'you', message: data.messagee },
            ]);
            messagees1 = 1; // Move this line inside the if block
        } else if (data.sendpartner === userName && messagees1 == 0) {
            setChatMessages((prevMessages) => [
                ...prevMessages,
                { senderName: partner, message: data.messagee.trim() },
            ]);
            messagees1 = 1; // Move this line inside the if block
        }
    });
```